# Crash dumps: ntdll.dll has version 6.2 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, crash-reports, crash-dumps

We're getting quite many strange crash dumps from our users: there, in OS Version "10.0.18363" is specified, but all system's DLL files has version "6.2.x" (i.e. Windows 8).

What is going on? How can this be?

[image]

Comment: By design, just the win10 version lies.  Programmers figured out they could get the OS version by checking the version of one of the common system DLLs.  They put a stop to that one as well.  Admirable effort, really.

Comment: I know it lies. But does it really lie even when generating a crash dump? This is really a bad behavior.

Comment: But you *do* know the version.  Build number 18362, that's version 1903, code name 19H1.  Decoder ring is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history).

Answer (score -1):

That's probably happen when Windows is not Windows, but maybe WINE, since normally the OS level DLL's (e.g. ntdll, kernel32.dll, kernelbase.dll, etc.) have the same major version number on a normal Microsoft OS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).